# after getting json using spring and .getBody, how can I retrieve specific values in the json file?

Tags: java, spring

snippet of json file

```
{
  "list": {
    "testSize": 1,
    "testype": [
      {
        "@name": "foo",

      },
      {
        "@name": "bar",
      },
```

I would like to get the values 'foo' and 'bar' from the json item '@name'.

I have a separate class that has the getters and setters, but as a novice, I feel as if I am not doing this part right.

```
 public class test {

@JsonProperty("@name")
public String name = "";

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}
```

-If I print out .getBody (via spring), I get the full json

-If I print out .getAdditionalProperties (my code), I get the full json

-If I print out .getName (my code), I get null... How do I get foo and bar?

Thanks

Comment: I would recommend looking into JSONPath: https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get a list of the test names you can do it like this:

```
final String json = "{\n" +
        "    \"list\": {\n" +
        "        \"testSize\": 1,\n" +
        "        \"testype\": [{\n" +
        "            \"@name\": \"foo\"\n" +
        "\n" +
        "        }, {\n" +
        "            \"@name\": \"bar\"\n" +
        "        }]\n" +
        "    }\n" +
        "}"

final JsonNode jsonNode = new ObjectMapper().readTree(json);
final List<String> testNames = jsonNode.findValuesAsText("@name");
```